# MIPS Hardware Multiplication ALU

Tags: assembly, mips, multiplication, alu

[image]

Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong? 
For every right-most bit of the multiplier, if I encounter a one, I add the multiplicand in the left side of the product. 
Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell, this appears to be a "shift and add" multiplier.

When you right shift the multiplier, you have to left shift the multiplicand. *Side note:* Actual ALUs may do mux/demux rather than actual shifts but the principle is the same.

While the input regs are 4 bits, since you're dealing with *signed* numbers you have to [effectively] sign extend before starting. And/or when right shifting it's an arithmetic right shift [shifts in the sign bit] instead of a logical right shift [shifts in a zero bit].

The ALU may or may not need 8 bit registers internally for multiplier/multiplicand, but it makes it easier to visualize to assume they are 8 bit as the product register must be 8 bits.

Here is the sequence for such a multiplier:

```
step    multiplier  multiplicand    product
        4           -6
1       00000100    11111010        00000000
2       00000010    11110100        00000000
3       00000001    11101000        11101000
4       00000000    11010000        11101000
5       00000000    10100000        11101000
6       00000000    01000000        11101000
7       00000000    10000000        11101000
8       00000000    00000000        11101000

step    multiplier  multiplicand    product
        -6          4
1       11111010    00000100        00000000
2       01111101    00001000        00001000
3       00111110    00010000        00001000
4       00011111    00100000        00101000
5       00001111    01000000        01101000
6       00000111    10000000        11101000
7       00000011    00000000        11101000
8       00000001    00000000        11101000
```

---

Here's the demo program that I used to generate the above:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef unsigned int u32;

#define CMAX    8
int cidx;
char cache[CMAX][80];

char *
binof(u32 x)
{
    char *bf;

    bf = cache[cidx++];
    if (cidx >= CMAX)
        cidx = 0;

    for (int idx = 7;  idx >= 0;  --idx, x >>= 1)
        bf[idx] = (x & 1) ? '1' : '0';

    return bf;
}

void
dostep(int step,u32 x,u32 y,u32 p)
{
    printf("%d\t\t%s\t%s\t\t%s\n",step,binof(x),binof(y),binof(p));
}

void
dotest(int x,int y)
{
    u32 xu;
    u32 yu;
    u32 p;

    xu = x;
    xu &= 0xFF;

    yu = y;
    yu &= 0xFF;

    printf("step\tmultiplier\tmultiplicand\tproduct\n");
    printf("\t\t%d\t\t\t%d\n",x,y);

    p = 0;
    for (int step = 1;  step <= 8;  ++step) {
        if (xu & 1)
            p += yu;
        dostep(step,xu,yu,p);
        xu >>= 1;
        yu <<= 1;
    }
}

// main -- main program
int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    char *cp;

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        switch (cp[1]) {
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

#if 0
    int x = atoi(argv[0]);
    int y = atoi(argv[1]);
#else
    int x = 4;
    int y = -6;
#endif
    dotest(x,y);
    printf("\n");
    dotest(y,x);

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

The above is for a simple multiplier. While keeping this model, we can refine it a bit with some observations.

If either the *multiplier* or the *multiplicand* becomes zero, there is no point to continuing the steps because the *product* will not change further. So, we can implement an "early escape" in the ALU control logic.

This helps a lot if the *multiplier* is 4: We can stop after step 3 (i.e. steps 4-8 aren't necessary).

But, this doesn't help as much if the *multiplier* is -6. We'd have to wait until after step 6 (i.e. steps 7-8 aren't necessary).

One way to mitigate this is to add a 4 bit comparator and swap the *multiplier* and *multiplicand* values [using a multiplexer controlled by the output of the comparator] *if* the *multiplier* is greater than the *multiplicand*, before sending the values into sign extension and, then, the ALU/multiplier.

All of the above can be done with a minimal amount of additional circuitry.

---

Here is the demo output for these various options:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TYPE: simple

step    multiplier  multiplicand    product
        4           -6
1       00000100    11111010        00000000
2       00000010    11110100        00000000
3       00000001    11101000        11101000
4       00000000    11010000        11101000
5       00000000    10100000        11101000
6       00000000    01000000        11101000
7       00000000    10000000        11101000
8       00000000    00000000        11101000
                                    -24

step    multiplier  multiplicand    product
        -6          4
1       11111010    00000100        00000000
2       01111101    00001000        00001000
3       00111110    00010000        00001000
4       00011111    00100000        00101000
5       00001111    01000000        01101000
6       00000111    10000000        11101000
7       00000011    00000000        11101000
8       00000001    00000000        11101000
                                    -24

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TYPE: autoswap

step    multiplier  multiplicand    product
        4           -6
1       00000100    11111010        00000000
2       00000010    11110100        00000000
3       00000001    11101000        11101000
4       00000000    11010000        11101000
5       00000000    10100000        11101000
6       00000000    01000000        11101000
7       00000000    10000000        11101000
8       00000000    00000000        11101000
                                    -24

step    multiplier  multiplicand    product
        4           -6
1       00000100    11111010        00000000
2       00000010    11110100        00000000
3       00000001    11101000        11101000
4       00000000    11010000        11101000
5       00000000    10100000        11101000
6       00000000    01000000        11101000
7       00000000    10000000        11101000
8       00000000    00000000        11101000
                                    -24

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TYPE: early escape

step    multiplier  multiplicand    product
        4           -6
1       00000100    11111010        00000000
2       00000010    11110100        00000000
3       00000001    11101000        11101000
                                    -24

step    multiplier  multiplicand    product
        -6          4
1       11111010    00000100        00000000
2       01111101    00001000        00001000
3       00111110    00010000        00001000
4       00011111    00100000        00101000
5       00001111    01000000        01101000
6       00000111    10000000        11101000
7       00000011    00000000        11101000
8       00000001    00000000        11101000
                                    -24

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TYPE: early escape with autoswap

step    multiplier  multiplicand    product
        4           -6
1       00000100    11111010        00000000
2       00000010    11110100        00000000
3       00000001    11101000        11101000
                                    -24

step    multiplier  multiplicand    product
        4           -6
1       00000100    11111010        00000000
2       00000010    11110100        00000000
3       00000001    11101000        11101000
                                    -24
```

---

Here is the updated demo program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

typedef unsigned int u32;

#define OPUT \
    do { \
        fputc(chr,stdout); \
        olen += 1; \
    } while (0)

#define CMAX    8
int cidx;
char cache[CMAX][80];

int opt_swap;
int opt_early;

char *
binof(u32 x)
{
    char *bf;

    bf = cache[cidx++];
    if (cidx >= CMAX)
        cidx = 0;

    for (int idx = 7;  idx >= 0;  --idx, x >>= 1)
        bf[idx] = (x & 1) ? '1' : '0';

    return bf;
}

void __attribute__((__format__(__printf__,1,2)))
outf(const char *fmt,...)
{
    va_list ap;
    int chr;
    char *bp;
    int olen;
    char ibuf[100];

    va_start(ap,fmt);
    vsprintf(ibuf,fmt,ap);
    va_end(ap);

    olen = 0;
    bp = ibuf;

    for (chr = *bp++;  chr != 0;  chr = *bp++) {
        if (chr != '\t') {
            OPUT;
            continue;
        }

        chr = ' ';
        OPUT;

        while ((olen % 4) != 0)
            OPUT;
    }
}

void
dostep(int step,u32 x,u32 y,u32 p)
{
    outf("%d\t\t%s\t%s\t\t%s\n",step,binof(x),binof(y),binof(p));
}

void
dotest(int x,int y)
{
    u32 mplier;
    u32 mcand;
    int tmp;
    u32 p;

    mplier = x;
    mplier &= 0xFF;

    mcand = y;
    mcand &= 0xFF;

    if (opt_swap && ((mplier & 0x0F) > (mcand & 0x0F))) {
        p = mplier;
        mplier = mcand;
        mcand = p;

        tmp = x;
        x = y;
        y = tmp;
    }

    outf("\n");
    outf("step\tmultiplier\tmultiplicand\tproduct\n");
    outf("\t\t%d\t\t\t%d\n",x,y);

    p = 0;
    for (int step = 1;  step <= 8;  ++step) {
        if (opt_early) {
            if (mplier == 0)
                break;
            if (mcand == 0)
                break;
        }

        if (mplier & 1)
            p += mcand;
        dostep(step,mplier,mcand,p);

        mplier >>= 1;
        mcand <<= 1;
    }

    outf("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t%d\n",(char) p);
}

// main -- main program
int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    char *cp;
    int x;
    int y;
    int sep;
    const char *name;

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        switch (cp[1]) {
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    switch (argc) {
    case 2:
        x = atoi(argv[0]);
        y = atoi(argv[1]);
        break;
    default:
        x = 4;
        y = -6;
        break;
    }

    sep = 0;
    for (opt_early = 0;  opt_early <= 1;  ++opt_early) {
        for (opt_swap = 0;  opt_swap <= 1;  ++opt_swap) {
            switch ((opt_early << 8) | (opt_swap << 0)) {
            case 0x0101:
                name = "early escape with autoswap";
                break;
            case 0x0100:
                name = "early escape";
                break;
            case 0x0001:
                name = "autoswap";
                break;
            default:
                name = "simple";
                break;
            }

            if (sep)
                outf("\n");
            sep = 1;

            for (int olen = 1;  olen <= 80;  ++olen)
                fputc('-',stdout);
            fputc('\n',stdout);

            outf("TYPE: %s\n",name);

            dotest(x,y);
            dotest(y,x);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your using the older algorithm which is much slow to process the multiplication.

Comment: Yes, no doubt. Shift-and-add is basic but slow. A "real" multiplier would use more circuitry to do this in a cycle or two. There isn't enough info in the diagram [e.g. what the control-test block does, what is in the feedback paths, or the combinatorial logic in the ALU block, etc.]. This info is implied, based on the model you've been studying (e.g. Wallace trees, etc.). So, based on what I could see and what you had in the table, I had to guess.